# Can not get the value using this in JavaScript class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am not able to get the data using `this` keyword in javascript class. Can anyone help why this is so? Please check the example below

```js
import axios from 'axios';

class Api {

    __HOST = "http://localhost:8080";
    __BASIC_AUTH = "Basic " + window.btoa('subhendu:mondal');
    __CONFIG = {
        headers : {
            authorization: this.__BASIC_AUTH
        }
    }

    welcomeMessage(){
        return axios.get("http://localhost:8080/welcome", this.__CONFIG);
    }

    Todo = {

        fetch: function(username, id){
            console.log(this.__CONFIG);
            return axios.get(`${this.__HOST}/users/${username}/todos/${id}`, this.__CONFIG);
        }
    }
}

export default new Api();
```

here methods inside `Todo` can able to get the `__CONFIG`. How can I get the value of `__CONFIG` , `__HOST` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert it to an arrow function, right now `this` refers to the functions own `this` value, which is not the classes `this` value.

This will allow you to bind `this` lexically (i.e where it is written in code), since arrow functions do not have a `this` property, it will go up the scope chain to look for the nearest `this` referenced, and it will arrive at the classes `this` value, which is what you want.

Comment: actually I have access ```this``` on welcomeMessage() but not in ```Todo.fetch()```, so I want to know is there any way to that.

Comment: Oho thanks, I got the solution by applying your concept.